# Calculus of Variations (Gelfand & Fomin): Proof of Functional Dependence Identity

Tags: calculus, variational-analysis

I'm on page 40 of the book (Section 2.10 - Variational Problems in Parametric Form). It states that for

$\int_{t_0}^{t_1}F\left(x,y,\frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}\right)\dot{x}dt=\int_{t_0}^{t_1}\Phi\left(x,y,\dot{x},\dot{y}\right)dt$

where the Euler equation for the left-hand side (LHS) is

$F_y-\frac{d}{dx}F_{y'}=0$

and the system of Euler equations for the right-hand side (RHS) are

$\Phi_x-\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_{\dot{x}}=0$

$\Phi_y-\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_{\dot{y}}=0$

that the system of Euler equations are dependent and related by

$\dot{x}\left(\Phi_x-\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_{\dot{x}}\right)+\dot{y}\left(\Phi_y-\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_{\dot{y}}\right)=0$.

Can someone prove this? I'm lost.

**Thoughts**

1. David Widder's "Advanced Calculus" tells us that two functions are dependent if their Jacobian vanishes (i.e. is identically zero)
2. Formulating the equation as

   $\frac{\dot{y}}{\dot{x}}=-\frac{\left(\Phi_x-\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_{\dot{x}}\right)}{\left(\Phi_y-\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_{\dot{y}}\right)}$

   looks eerily similar to implicit differentiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling

$$
\Phi(x,y,\dot x, \dot y)=F\left(x,y,\frac{\dot y }{\dot x}\right)\dot x
$$

and performing

$$
\dot{x}\left(\Phi_x-\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_{\dot{x}}\right)+\dot{y}\left(\Phi_y-\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_{\dot{y}}\right)
$$

we get after some algebra

$$
\dot x\left((\dot x-\dot x)F_x+(\dot y-\dot y)F_y\right) = 0
$$

NOTE

$$
\dot y \left(F^{(0,1,0)} \dot x-F^{(1,0,1)} \dot x+F^{(0,0,2)} \left(\frac{\ddot x \dot y}{\left(\dot x\right)^2}-\frac{\ddot y}{\dot x}\right)-F^{(0,1,1)} \dot y\right)+\dot x
   \left(\frac{F^{(0,0,1)} \ddot y}{\dot x}-\frac{F^{(0,0,1)} \ddot x \dot y}{\left(\dot x\right)^2}-F^{(0,0,1)} \left(\frac{\ddot y}{\dot x}-\frac{\ddot x
   \dot y}{\left(\dot x\right)^2}\right)+\frac{\dot y \left(F^{(1,0,1)} \dot x+F^{(0,0,2)} \left(\frac{\ddot y}{\dot x}-\frac{\ddot x \dot y}{\left(\dot x\right)^2}\right)+F^{(0,1,1)}
   \dot y\right)}{\dot x}-F^{(0,1,0)} \dot y\right) = 0
$$

NOTE

Considering

$$
I = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} F(x,y,y')dx
$$

we have

$$
y' = \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{\dot y}{\dot x}\to dx = \dot x dt
$$

and then

$$
I = \int_{t_1}^{t_2}F\left(x,y,\frac{\dot y}{\dot x}\right)\dot x dt
$$

then

$$
\Phi_x = F_x \dot x\\
\Phi_{\dot x} = F-\dot x F_{y'}\frac{\dot y}{(\dot x)^2} = F-y' F_{y'}
$$

etc. Having in mind the identity for $g(x,y,y')$

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(y'g_{y'}-g\right) = y'\frac{d}{dx}g_{y'}-g_x-g_y y'=-y'\left(g_y-\frac{d}{dx}g_{y'}\right)-g_x
$$

we have

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_{\dot x} = \dot x\frac{d}{dx}\left(F-y' F_{y'}\right) = \dot x\left\{y'\left(F_y-\frac{d}{dx}F_{y'}\right)+F_x\right\}
$$

and also

$$
\Phi_x = F_x\dot x,\ \ \ \Phi_{\dot y} = \dot x F_{y'}\frac{1}{\dot x} = F_{y'}
$$

So concluding with $\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_{\dot y} = \dot x\frac{d}{dx}F_{y'}$

$$
\Phi_x-\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_{\dot x} = -\dot y\left(F_y-\frac{d}{dx}F_{y'}\right)\\
\Phi_y-\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_{\dot y} = \dot x\left(F_y-\frac{d}{dx}F_{y'}\right)
$$

Comment: Can you please show the algebra?

Comment: @A.Hendry See note attached.

Comment: Was this from Wolfram?

Comment: Also, I still don't understand how the original identity was derived. The book just says it can be "easily verified". Do you know how it was derived?

Comment: Thank you, by the way, for your help!

Comment: @A.Hendry Please see attached note.

Comment: Most excellent! This is extremely helpful. Thank you!

Comment: For $\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_{\dot{x}}$, I get


$\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_{\dot{x}}=\dot{x}\frac{d}{dx}\left(F+y'F_{y'}\right)$
$=\dot{x}\left(F_{x}+y''F_{y'}+y'F_{y'x}\right)$


Is that right?

Comment: Can you show me how to calculate $\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_\dot{x}$?

Comment: Actually, is it just $\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_\dot{x}=\dot{x}\frac{d}{dx}\left(F-y'F_{y'}\right)=\dot{x}\left(F_{x}+F_{y}y'-y'\frac{d}{dx}F_{y'}\right)=\dot{x}F_{x}+\dot{y}\left(F_{y}-\frac{d}{dx}F_{y'}\right)$

Comment: @A.Hendry Please. See the development for $\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_{\dot x}$

Comment: Thank you! This is the answer

Comment: Can you try your hand at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3132860/calculus-of-variations-gelfand-fomin-proof-of-eulers-equation-for-constrai