# Calculus of Variations (Gelfand & Fomin): Proof of Euler's Equation for Constrained Variation

Tags: euler-lagrange-equation, variational-analysis

I am in Section 2.12.1 of ***Calculus of Variations*** by Gelfand & Fomin. I am attempting to follow the proof of the Euler equation for Constrained Variation (Theorem 1, pg. 42). However, I'm confused at certain steps (please see **Proof** and **My Questions** below) and would appreciate some help.

**Theorem**

*"Given the functional*

$$J[y]=\int_{a}^{b}F(x,y,y')dx$$

*and admissible curves, $y=y(x)$, satisfying* ***boundary conditions***

\begin{aligned}
y(a)=A \\
y(b)=B \\
\end{aligned}

*and* ***constraint***

$$K[y]=\int_{a}^{b}G(x,y,y')dx=C$$

*for some functional $K$, integrand $G$, and constant $C$, let $J$ have an extremum for $y=y(x)$*
      *where $y$ is not an extremal of $K$.Then there exists some constant, $\lambda$, such that $y$ is an*
      *extremal of the functional*

$$\int_{a}^{b}\left(F+\lambda G\right)dx$$

*satisfying the* ***constrained Euler equation***

$$\left(F_{y}-\frac{d}{dx}F_{y'}\right)+\lambda \left(G_{y}-\frac{d}{dx}G_{y'}\right)=0."$$

**Proof**

Choose two points $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ in $[a,b]$ such that $x_{1}$ is arbitrary and $x_{2}$ satisfies

$$\left.\frac{\delta G}{\delta y}\right|_{x=x_{2}}\ne0.$$

(i.e. the variational derivative of $G$ at $x_{2}$ is nonzero). We know the point $x_{2}$ exists because $y$ is
      not an extremal of $K$.

Give $y$ an increment $\Delta y$

$$\Delta y=\delta_{1}y(x)+\delta_{2}y(x)$$

where

$\delta_{1}y(x)\ne 0$ only in a neighborhood of $x_{1}$,
                                                      $\delta_{2}y(x)\ne 0$ only in a neighborhood of $x_{2}$.

(***NOTE:*** The *increment* $h(x)$ of $J$ is also called the *variation* of $y(x)$, such that $h$ is written as

$$h=h(x)=\delta y(x).)$$

Since an arbitrary functional, $H$, can be written as

$$\Delta H \equiv H[y+h]-H[y]=\left\{\left.\frac{\delta H}{\delta y}\right|_{x=x_{0}}+\epsilon\right\}\Delta \sigma$$

if

$h(x)\ne 0$ in a neighborhood of $x_{0}$, and
                                                $\Delta \sigma$ is the area between $y=h(x)$ and the $x$-axis

we can write $\Delta J$ as

$$\Delta J=\left\{\left.\frac{\delta F}{\delta y}\right|_{x=x_{1}}+\epsilon_{1}\right\}\Delta \sigma_{1}+\left\{\left.\frac{\delta F}{\delta y}\right|_{x=x_{2}}+\epsilon_{2}\right\}\Delta \sigma_{2}\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

where

$$\Delta \sigma_{1}=\int_{a}^{b}\delta_{1}y(x)dx$$
$$\Delta \sigma_{2}=\int_{a}^{b}\delta_{2}y(x)dx$$

and

$$\lim_{\Delta \sigma_{1} \to 0}\epsilon_{1}=0,$$
$$\lim_{\Delta \sigma_{2} \to 0}\epsilon_{2}=0.$$

Let

$$y^{*}(x) \equiv y(x)+\Delta y = y  +\delta_{1} y +\delta_{2}y$$

and require

$$K[y^{*}]=K[y].$$

Then

$$
\begin{align}
\Delta K & = K[y^{*}]-K[y] \\
 & =K[y+\Delta y]-K[y] \\
 & =0
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
\Delta K & = \left\{\left.\frac{\delta G}{\delta y}\right|_{x=x_{1}}+\epsilon'_{1}\right\}\Delta \sigma_{1}+\left\{\left.\frac{\delta G}{\delta y}\right|_{x=x_{2}}+\epsilon'_{2}\right\}\Delta \sigma_{2}=0.
\end{align}\tag{2}\label{eq2}
$$

Since $\left.\frac{\delta G}{\delta y}\right|_{x=x_{2}}\ne0$ by our definition, we can write  $\Delta \sigma_{2}$ as

$$
\Delta \sigma_{2} = -\left\{ \frac{\left.\frac{\delta G}{\delta y}\right|_{x=x_{1}}}{\left.\frac{\delta G}{\delta y}\right|_{x=x_{2}}} + \epsilon' \right\} \Delta \sigma_{1}\tag{3}\label{eq3}
$$

where

$$\lim_{\Delta \sigma_{1} \to 0}\epsilon'=0.$$

Defining

$$\lambda \equiv -\left\{ \frac{\left.\frac{\delta F}{\delta y}\right|_{x=x_{2}}}{\left.\frac{\delta G}{\delta y}\right|_{x=x_{2}}}\right\}$$

we can substitute \eqref{eq3} and $\lambda$ into our expression for $\Delta J$, \eqref{eq1}, to get

$$\Delta J = \left\{ \left.\frac{\delta F}{\delta y}\right|_{x=x_{1}} + \lambda \left.\frac{\delta G}{\delta y}\right|_{x=x_{1}} \right\}\Delta \sigma_{1} + \epsilon \Delta \sigma_{1}.\tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

The principal linear part of this term is the first term on the RHS. Hence,

$$\delta J = \left\{ \left.\frac{\delta F}{\delta y}\right|_{x=x_{1}} + \lambda \left.\frac{\delta G}{\delta y}\right|_{x=x_{1}} \right\}\Delta \sigma_{1}$$

and since the necessary condition for a weak extremum is $\delta J[h]=0$ and $\Delta \sigma_{1}$ is nonzero while
      $x_{1}$ is arbitrary, we have

$$\left(F_{y}-\frac{d}{dx}F_{y'}\right)+\lambda \left(G_{y}-\frac{d}{dx}G_{y'}\right)=0.$$

**My Questions**

1. How do we get from \eqref{eq2} to \eqref{eq3}? I know it's not simple division since $\epsilon' \ne \frac{\epsilon'_{1}}{\epsilon'_{2}} $.
2. How do you substitute $\Delta \sigma_{2}$ \eqref{eq3} and $\lambda$ into $\Delta J$ \eqref{eq1} to get \eqref{eq4}? I have extra terms involving $\epsilon_{1}$, $\epsilon_{2}$, and $\epsilon'$ that aren't cancelling.

Comment: Other texts (e.g. _Calculus of Variations_ by R. Weinstock and _Calculus of Variations_ by Bruce van Brunt) express $y^{*}$ as $y^{*}(x)=y(x)+\epsilon_{1} \eta_{1}(x) + \epsilon_{2} \eta_{2}(x)$ where $\eta_{1}(x_{1})=\eta_{1}(x_{2})=\eta_{2}(x_{1})=\eta_{2}(x_{2})=0$. They then plug $y^{*}$ and $y'^{*}$ into $J$ and $K$ and express them as functions of $\epsilon_{1}$ and $\epsilon_{2}$ for fixed choice of $\eta_{1}(x)$ and $\eta_{2}(x)$. Lastly, they state that $\epsilon_{1}$ and $\epsilon_{2}$ are functionally dependent by the implicit function theorem.

Comment: In the above, either $\epsilon_{2}=\epsilon_{2}(\epsilon_{1})$, or vice-versa, provided $\nabla K(x, y^{*}, y'^{*}) \ne 0$, where $\nabla$ denotes the operator $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon_{1}},\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon_{2}}\right).$

Comment: Their functional dependence is made visually apparent by the fact that $K=K(\epsilon_{1},\epsilon_{2})=$ _constant_.

Comment: Do any of the 3 above comments help answer my questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint.

Having in mind that $\epsilon_1',\epsilon_2'\to 0$ as $\Delta\sigma_1,\Delta\sigma_2\to 0$, 
from (3) if $\Delta\sigma_1\to 0$ then $\Delta\sigma_2\to 0$ and

$$
\frac{a+\epsilon_1'}{b+\epsilon_2'} = \frac ab + \epsilon'
$$

with $\epsilon'=\frac{b\epsilon_1'-a\epsilon_2'}{b(b+\epsilon_2')}$ where $\epsilon'\to 0$ when $\Delta\sigma_1\to 0$

Comment: This is great! Would you be able to do the same for my second question?

Comment: Nevermind on that, I got it. The result of the second question follows naturally as it involves all terms that multiply an $\epsilon$, which can be redefined as a single $\epsilon$ and vanish with $\sigma_{1} \to 0$. Bravo! You are certainly a mathemagician. It was so simple it was hard!! A++!

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have an answer, and my comments did help.

Writing $\Delta \sigma_{2}$ as a function of $\Delta \sigma_{1}$ (by the Implicit Function theorem) and that $\epsilon_{1}$, $\epsilon_{2}$, $\epsilon_{1}'$, $\epsilon_{2}'$, $\Delta \sigma_{1}$, and $\Delta \sigma_{2}$ are all controlled by closeness to $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ (they are all non-zero **ONLY** *in **a neighborhood of $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$***, respectively), we can let $x$ approach $x_{1}$ so that $\epsilon_{2}$, $\epsilon_{2}'$, and $\Delta \sigma_{2}$ vanish. Then$\Delta J$ and $\Delta \sigma_{2}$ are functions only of variables near $x_{1}$ (i.e. $\epsilon_{1}, \epsilon_{1}'$, and $\Delta \sigma_{1}$). (**See [details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIQz3.jpg)**).

Comment: This might not actually be correct since $\Delta \sigma_{2}$ vanishes outside the neighborhood fo $x_{2}$ by definition...